# jquery keypress loop while checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope you help me to do this stuff :)

What we have:
checkbox to turn on/off script execution
keyboard hotkeys, A and B

What I need:

```
if $('checkbox':checked){
    // infinite loop simultaion of keyboard pressed keys "A" and "B"
    // better with delay like 1 second we simulate "A: keypress, after 1 second
    // script simulate "B" keypress
   // untill checkbox is checked
   // if checkbox not checked - stop script or do nothing
}
```

Big thanks in advance for all people who respond to this topic ;)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, we expect you to have a go at your code first by yourself. Then, when you have a bug or get stuck on a specific technical problem, then come to us and explain what you've tried and we'll help you solve the bug. We won't write your code for you.

Comment: @TarynEast gonna copy your *"what have you tried"* messages!!

Comment: @charlietfl :) I've written it so many times now, it's become reflex :D I should also add that I worked hard on finding a way to say what we need from newbies while also respecting that they are newcomers to our culture and aren't familiar with what is expected...

Comment: @TarynEast I am total JS/jQuery newbie, and for me it's hard to write any code :-/

Comment: I know - code is difficult... If you need some help - you may need to find yourself a mentor in your local JS community. In the meantime... why don't you start by trying to do the bits you do know  - chip away at things like the if/else statements (even if you don't know how to write the conditionals yet). Then the next step is to imagine how you'd write it if you could make up the language to work the way you wish it did.. (this is pseudocode). The next step is to go look up whether jquery really does the things you imagined and if they're named differently then change them to the right names

Comment: What you're finally left with you can then try running - you'll get bugs, but that's ok... because then the next steps are: for each one, google the error message and see whether there are articles written on how to fix it. Fix everything you can. The final step is if there's anything left over causing a bug - you can then come here and write a question and show us the code you have... and we'll be happy to help with that :)